# Calling a method from on_release event of a button in a pop up

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

As I mentioned in the title, I am creating a pop up with a video and two buttons - Now I want to implement functionality for those buttons - so, I have created a method to call when a button pressed from the pop up I have created - But this always returns TypeError: addme() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) - If I make this method as static then it returns AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'on_text'

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import WidgetException
from functools import partial


kv = """
<MainPage>:
    manager:screen_mgr
    do_default_tab: False
    textinputtext: waybill.text
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_mgr
        #transition: FadeTransition
        Screen:
            manager: screen_mgr
            id: intro
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            name: 'User'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'center'
                anchor_y: 'center'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 20
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'left'
                        size_hint_x: .5
                        TextInput:
                            id: waybill
                            width: 20
                            text: root.textinputtext
                            multiline: False
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            size_hint_y: None
                            font_size: 30
                            focus: True
                            on_text: self.text
                            on_text_validate:app.on_waybill()
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: "Compare"
                            on_release: root.compareClicked()
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            id: statebtn
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: "State"
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                anchor_y: 'top'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y': .5}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            on_release:root.current = root.switch_screen()
                            text: "Admin"
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: intro.name
        # store a screen name to link the tab to a screen
        screen: intro.name
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)
waybill = TextInput(text="Enter Waybill No.", multiline=False)

class MainPage(TabbedPanel):

    screen_mgr = ObjectProperty(None)
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_text')
        self.textinputtext = "Enter Waybill No."

    def on_text(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_text_validate(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_focus(self, obj, focused):
        if not focused:
            self.dispatch('on_text_validate')

    def compareClicked(self):
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.value = 1
        print (self.on_text())
        if self.on_text()!='Enter Waybill No.' :
            self.popup_1()

    def popup_1(self):
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(10))
        popup = Popup(title='Warning: Please Place', title_size=(30),
                      title_align='center', content=self.box,
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                      auto_dismiss=False)
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="YES TO COMPARE", on_release=partial(self.addme)))
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="NO TO GO BACK", on_release=popup.dismiss))
        popup.bind()
        popup.open()

    #@staticmethod
    def addme(self):
        print (self.on_text())

    def switch_screen(self):
        self.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
        self.manager.current = self.manager.previous()
        return self.manager.current

    def switch_to(self, header):
        self.manager.current = header.screen
        self.current_tab.state = "normal"
        header.state = 'down'
        self._current_tab = header

class KartScanApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPage()

    def on_waybill(self):
        waybill.bind(text=MainPage.on_text)
        return waybill.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KartScanApp().run()
```

Please help me in resolving this, I'm missing some basics here

Comment: can you reduce your example to as few lines of code as possible. Ideally also without dependencies apart from kivy. From a first look the `on_text` looks really strange, also no need to register as already registered. I will take a deeper look if you reduce your code.

Comment: Hi @palimpalim,I've removed external dependencies and removed some unnecessary methods, can you please look into it and suggest me what is the problem?

Comment: Can't you make an example which is just a couple of lines and has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know what is the problem with my code, whenever I'm calling any method from on_release event of a button in a pop up, the method always holds a button a object - So when you are creating a method accept one more argument which can hold the button object. Following is the solution :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import WidgetException
from functools import partial


kv = """
<MainPage>:
    manager:screen_mgr
    do_default_tab: False
    textinputtext: waybill.text
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_mgr
        #transition: FadeTransition
        Screen:
            manager: screen_mgr
            id: intro
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            name: 'User'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'center'
                anchor_y: 'center'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 20
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'left'
                        size_hint_x: .5
                        TextInput:
                            id: waybill
                            width: 20
                            text: root.textinputtext
                            multiline: False
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            size_hint_y: None
                            font_size: 30
                            focus: True
                            on_text: self.text
                            on_text_validate:app.on_waybill()
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: "Compare"
                            on_release: root.compareClicked()
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            id: statebtn
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: "State"
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                anchor_y: 'top'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y': .5}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            on_release:root.current = root.switch_screen()
                            text: "Admin"
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: intro.name
        # store a screen name to link the tab to a screen
        screen: intro.name
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)
waybill = TextInput(text="Enter Waybill No.", multiline=False)

class MainPage(TabbedPanel):

    screen_mgr = ObjectProperty(None)
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_text')
        self.textinputtext = "Enter Waybill No."

    def on_text(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_text_validate(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_focus(self, obj, focused):
        if not focused:
            self.dispatch('on_text_validate')

    def compareClicked(self):
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.value = 1
        print (self.on_text())
        if self.on_text()!='Enter Waybill No.' :
            self.popup_1()

    def popup_1(self):
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(10))
        popup = Popup(title='Warning: Please Place', title_size=(30),
                      title_align='center', content=self.box,
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                      auto_dismiss=False)
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="YES TO COMPARE", on_release=partial(self.addme)))
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="NO TO GO BACK", on_release=popup.dismiss))
        popup.bind()
        popup.open()

    #@staticmethod
    def addme(self, button):
        print (self.on_text())

    def switch_screen(self):
        self.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
        self.manager.current = self.manager.previous()
        return self.manager.current

    def switch_to(self, header):
        self.manager.current = header.screen
        self.current_tab.state = "normal"
        header.state = 'down'
        self._current_tab = header

class KartScanApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPage()

    def on_waybill(self):
        waybill.bind(text=MainPage.on_text)
        return waybill.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KartScanApp().run()
```